# loop and merge to create new list

Tags: python, loops, join, merge

what is the most efficient way of doing the following?

```
A = ["A","B","C"]
B = [range(19,21)]
```

Outcome of the list:

```
C = ["A19", "B19", "C19", "A20", "B20", "C20"]
```

thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
A = ["A","B","C"]
B = range(19,21)
print([x+str(y) for y in B for x in A])
```

Or if version is above Python 3.6:

```
print([f"{x}{y}" for y in B for x in A])
```

Output:

```
['A19', 'B19', 'C19', 'A20', 'B20', 'C20']
```

**Edit:**

Use this:

```
A = ["X","Y","Z"]
B = range(19,21)
C = [x+str(y) for y in B for x in A]
print(C)
curveexpression = ""
for zoo in "Animal":
    for month in C:
        arrival += "[%s,%s];" % (zoo, month)
print(arrival)
```

Comment: what is the proper way of doing the following?

A= ["X","Y","Z"]
B = range(19,21)
C = [x+str(y) for y in B for x in A]
arrival= ""

for zoo in ["Animal"]:
    for month in [C]:
        arrival += "[%s,%s];" % (zoo, month)

i couldn't get the following,                                                                 
[Animal,X19];[Animal,Y19];[Animal,Z19];[Animal,X20];[Animal;Y20];[Animal,Z20]

Comment: @VincentHeng Copy the below part of my post, that will work

Answer (score 5):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) could also be used:

```
from itertools import product

A = ["A","B","C"]
C = [a + str(n) for n, a in product(range(19, 21), A)]
```

note that there are different ways to format the string (`a`) and the number `n` to a single string:

```
a + str(n)
"{}{}".format(a, n)
f"{a}{n}"  # for python >= 3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following listcomp:

```
from itertools import product

A = ["A","B","C"]
B = range(19,21)

[i + j for i, j in product(A, map(str, B))]
# ['A19', 'A20', 'B19', 'B20', 'C19', 'C20']
```

or

```
from itertools import product
from operator import concat

[concat(*i) for i in product(A, map(str, B))]
# ['A19', 'A20', 'B19', 'B20', 'C19', 'C20']
```

If you want to build a list from a range use the function `list()`:

```
list(range(19, 21))
# [19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

For range in the list:

```
B = [*range(19, 21)]:

C = [a + str(b) for b in B for a in A]
```